# How to update rows in the same table if the ids are the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-update

I have a database that I created from screen scraping from this company. However, because the company has changed the way they display data, I want to update my database too. Here's an example of what I want to do: (A: Name, B: ID)

```
A                            B 
Apple                        0020
McIntosh Apple               0020
Ambrosia Apple               0021
Cortland Apple               0022
Apple                        0022
```

As you can see from the table above, the first row only has the name "Apple" and the key "0020", but the second row has the different name but the same key. Similarly, the forth and the fifth row has the similar problem. What I need to do is check each row, and if the ids are the same, then copy the name which has longer length to the shorter one so that the names for each ids are the same. But I'm not sure how to do this. I'm using SQL Server 2008. Can you pleas help? I'm also trying to achieve this using SSIS, and I'm still playing around with this. Since I'm not very experienced with SQL query, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the logic to write the query.

Thank you

Comment: So you don't mmind duplicate rows finally ? I.e Mcin apple 0020, Mcin apple 0020 etc. ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know where to begin. Can you give me some ideas? I'm thinking something along like update table set A = select max(length(A)) from table. But what I can't understand is how is it going to check the B values and update it

Comment: I do, but for now I'm fine with duplicate. Cause I'll be using SSIS to split the tables to create multiple ones for each column. the apple table is just an example.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment: I meant it like this:  update table set A = select A from table where length(A) = (select max(length(A)) from table)

Comment: Honestly, the best practice is to ensure that you have unique identity keys.  If the second column MUST be able to have duplicates, add a third colum named RecordId and use it as a real unique ID.

Comment: @DavidStratton - I was wondering if you could give me some feedback for my answer. I'd appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidStratton that's a valued suggestion. The question I had is from a bigger database. When I created it, I had very limited knowledge about the data. Now that I know what those data mean, I immediately saw the issue with creating database like that. That's why I want to split the table into multiple tables so that the tables are normalized and contains no duplicates. Your suggestion is appreciated since I might need it in the future. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple self join and length of column A can help us here. Once we get the query for that, we will use that query to perform an update (statement). Assume that the name of your table is junk.

Would'nt it be nice and easy if there was a column C which contained the longer name for each row in A ? In that case we could simply issue a statement UPDATE Junk SET A = C. Lets try to make this happen somehow. Lets get that "column C" first with the query below -

```
select *
from
(
select j1.A as A1,j1.B as B1,j2.A as C1 
from Junk as j1
inner join Junk as j2 --self join
on j1.B = j2.B
and LEN(j1.A) < LEN(j2.A)
) as s1
```

Now lets try to make the results of this query "join" our Junk table and create 
a column C. Once we do that properly, we can do a "simple" update. In the above
query, replace select * with an update statement as follows -

```
update Junk 
set Junk.A = s1.C1
from
(
select j1.A as A1,j1.B as B1,j2.A as C1 
from Junk as j1
inner join Junk as j2
on j1.B = j2.B
and LEN(j1.A) < LEN(j2.A)
) as s1
WHERE Junk.A = s1.A1
and Junk.B = s1.B1
```

To verify if this query works, run the first query. If you get zero rows, it works.

You can delete the duplicates or keep them if you wish.